# CartoDB: Trigger InfoWindow from inside another InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js

Is there a easy way (maybe even generic solution) to trigger opening the InfoWindow of Marker 1 from inside the InfoWindow of Marker 0?

The goal would be to «jump» from marker to marker right from inside the InfoWindows (à la «Next Location»-Links).

Answer (score 1):

No standard solution, you should get the position and id's of your features and bind something like this:

```
function openInfowindow(layer, latlng, cartodb_id) {
  layer.trigger('featureClick', null, latlng, null, { cartodb_id: cartodb_id}, 0);
}
```

as is shown here on [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/xavijam/ae5317bddf1256f91534). You should build your own infowindow and disable JavaScript sanitization on it so you can have your functionality attached to them.

Maybe you want to consider using [Odyssey.JS](https://github.com/CartoDB/odyssey.js) since it provides a similar functionality?